# Windows authentication with custom authorization requirement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to do ASP.NET Core 2 api with windows authentication. I need some unusual authorization requirements so I decided to create my own requirement for a policy.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    (...)

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new MyRequirement())
        );
    });
}
```

My requirement:

```
public class MyRequirement: IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    (...)
}
```

Handler for it:

```
public class MyHandler: AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>
{
    public IService userService;

    public MyHandler(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
    {
        (...)

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And obviously, Authorize attribute for my method:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
{
    (...)
}
```

But when I try to access such a method I get:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
>   there was no DefaultForbidScheme found.

I wasted a lot of time trying to fix it. Why is it happening and how can I get it working?

Everything happens locally, on IISExpress.

Comment: Did you called`services.AddAuthentication()` on the `ConfigureServices` method of Startup class? If yes, can I see how you called that method?

Comment: Add services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

Comment: services.AddAuthentication() makes no difference, services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); causes 403 error